# My First MySQL Stored Procedure for updating two table have some error

Tags: php, mysql, stored-procedures

I went through the internet to find the best practice for updating two table from one form and I decided to create stored procedure in MySQL for inserting data.I am not sure how to pass datetime or timestamp from the stored procedure to insert into table. I am very new to MySQL and got couple of error. My sproc looks like this:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `sp_insertUser`(
IN userId int(11) 
, IN userName varchar(15)
, IN passWord varchar(15)
, IN create_DateStamp datetime
, IN update_DateStamp datetime

BEGIN
INSERT INTO `Php_Project`.`User`
(userId,
userName,
passWord,
create_DateStamp,
update_DateStamp)


    VALUES
    (
    userId,
    userName,
    passWord,
    create_DateStamp,
    update_DateStamp
    );
```

Also I have trigger for create_Datestamp as:

```
USE `Php_Project`;
DELIMITER $$
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` TRIGGER `User_BINS` BEFORE INSERT ON `User` FOR EACH        ROW
BEGIN
    -- Set the creation date
SET new.create_DateStamp= now();
End
```

I have created this in MySQL Workbenck. Error comes when I try to call sproc in query window as:

```
CALL `Php_Project`.`sp_insertUser`(1234,surajnew55,password,now(),now());
```

The error says:Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'surajnew55' in 'field list'    0.000 sec
Please help me to figure out how thing work in this case.

Comment: Change the input arg 'IN userName varchar(15)' to be 'IN theUserName varchar(15)'. Then change the VALUES part to use 'theUserName' instead of 'userName'. Am pretty sure the stored project is getting confused by the userName column that you are overloading as an input arg. Do the same for all those column/inp arg names so that the column name differs from the input arg name.

Comment: @robnick you nailed it. Thanks dude.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try like this

String values should be passed inside the quotes in MySQL

```
CALL `Php_Project`.`sp_insertUser`(1234,'surajnew55','password',now(),now());
```